# What is the different between API functions AllocConsole and AttachConsole(-1)?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, console

Could you please explain me, what is the different between API functions `AllocConsole` and `AttachConsole(-1)` ? I mean if `AttachConsole` gets `ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS(DWORD)-1`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, the fundamental difference is:

- `AllocConsole()` will create a new console (and attach to it)
- `AttachConsole( ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS /* -1 */)` will not create a new console, it will attach to the existing console of the parent process.

In the first case you get a whole new console window, in the second case, you use an existing console window.

Of course, if you're already attached to a console (ie., you're a console mode program launched from cmd.exe) there's not much difference - you'll get an error with either API.

Also note that just because you detach from a console doesn't mean the detached console will be useful - for example, if you're a console process launched from a cmd window, that window essentially blocks until your process ends.

Some code to play with:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int ch;
    BOOL bResult;

    printf( "default console\n");
    ch = getchar();

    bResult = FreeConsole();
    bResult = AllocConsole();    
    printf( "AllocConsole()\n");
    ch = getchar();

    bResult = FreeConsole();
    bResult = AttachConsole( ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);    
    printf( "AttachConsole( ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)\n");
    ch = getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can this be used in C#.Net to create a console window for an executable compiled as a Windows Program (and not a Console Program)?

Comment: Yes it can.  It is however far easier to get a console, just change the project's Output Type to Console Application.

Comment: @configuratoir - as far as I know you can do this but I think you'll have to use p/invoke to call the Win32 APIs (not a big deal for these APIs) - I'm not sure if there's a framework equivalent.

Comment: @nobugz - Yes, you can. See more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472282/show-console-in-windows-application#476894

Comment: @abatishchev: Nice link to a dead link... not.

Comment: @7vujy0f0hy oh, I'm sorry that a linked posted 8 years ago doesn't work for you anymore. Never happened before and please rest assured won't happen again. Please accept my sincere apology. P.S. Thanks for the edit. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's a function called `CreateConsole`, but there's [`AllocConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Assuming that's what you meant, I think the difference is that `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)` can [return `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681952.aspx) if the parent process doesn't have a console.

Try running this code from both a command prompt and Start -> Run:

```
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment ( lib, "user32.lib" )

int main()
{
    BOOL b;
    char msg[1024];

    b = FreeConsole();
    sprintf(msg, "%d", b);
    MessageBox(NULL, msg, "FreeConsole", 0);

    b = AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
    sprintf(msg, "%d", b);
    MessageBox(NULL, msg, "AttachConsole", 0);

    return 0;
}
```

When run from a command prompt, two message boxes containing a `1` are displayed, meaning both calls succeeded. When run from Start -> Run, the first box contains `1` and the second contains `0`, meaning that only the first call succeeded. The second one fails because explorer.exe (which is the parent of a process launched from Start -> Run) doesn't have a console.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows 7, when you execute `cmd.exe`, `CreateProcess` will have the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag, which will allocate a new console rather than being attached to the parent console (which is default behaviour when the PE header contains `Subsystem = 3` i.e. `IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_CUI` indicating that it is a console application). This means that `AllocConsole` will be called before the `.exe` image entry point in the current process address space.

`AllocConsole` creates a new `conhost.exe` instance, which paints the GUI window, handles the mouse and keyboard events and maintains and writes to the the input buffer and maintains and reads from the screen buffer, and when there is a keyboard event, it updates the input buffer. `AllocConsole` also sets the `stdin` handle in the `ParameterBlock` in the `cmd.exe` process PEB to the console input buffer and the `stdout` and `stderr` to the the console pseudohandles, and sets the `ConsoleHandle` in the ParameterBlock`to the PID of the`conhost.exe` instance that it is attached to.

`cmd.exe` is a console application written in C, like `diskpart.exe` or `setx.exe`, which displays the command prompt to the screen buffer (`stdout` of `cmd.exe`) and reads a command from the `stdin` *of `cmd.exe`* and interprets the key press events to display to `stdout` as well as determine what command to call and what to display to `stdout` as a result (which might be a file in the handle in the PEB and not sent to `conhost`). A *command* itself has an `stdin` of either nothing, the read side of an anonymous pipe, a file or the `con` file.

`cmd.exe` calls functions like `WriteFile` which will call `WriteConsole` (which is an alias of `WriteConsoleA`) if it is writing to a standard handle (otherwise it calls `NtWriteFile`). This will initiate an ALPC call to `conhost.exe` PID in `ParameterBlock->ConsoleHandle`, passing the console pseudohandle and the buffer to write the result to (or the buffer to read from).

When you execute `cmd /c` from inside `cmd.exe`, it creates a child `cmd.exe`, but does not supply `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, which results in the child `cmd.exe` attaching to the same visible console i.e. `conhost.exe` instance and `AttachConsole` is called before the entry point. This is not the case with a child created with `admin /c` (admin version of `cmd.exe`) if done in a non-elevated `cmd.exe`, which needs to have a new `conhost.exe` instance because it has different privileges. Similarly, when starting a program, `start` supplies `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, which opens a new `conhost.exe` for its child process, but `call` and specifying the program filename + extension as a raw command do not open another console window, but attach to the parent. `cmd /c diskpart` creates a `cmd.exe` child that attaches to the console that the parent is attached to and then that child creates its own child `diskpart.exe`, which attaches to the console that the parent is attached to.

When you execute a GUI application, it is not allocated or attached to a console. If you use `AllocConsole` within the application, it will create a new `conhost.exe` console window (which can be hidden by the application, i.e. blender has `window > toggle system console`, and it does this by getting a handle to the `conhost.exe` console window and then using using `ShowWindow` with `SW_HIDE` on it), but will not create a child process, because it is the console window of the current process, so now there will be 2 windows. You can also instead attach to a console (using `AttachConsole`) belonging to a process of `pid`. `AttachConsole(-1)` attaches to the parent `pid`. This will use the `conhost` that that process is attached to.

You cannot `AttachConsole` if you are already attached to a console without using `FreeConsole` and you can't `AttachConsole` to connect to the parent's console if you create the process with `DETACHED_PROCESS`. `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` has the same effect as `DETACHED_PROCESS` in that it does not attach to or allocate a console for the console application but does allow it to attach to the parent console.

Comment: "you can't `AttachConsole` to connect to the parent's console if you create the process with `DETACHED_PROCESS`" Are you sure? I made a little test program that tried this and it seemed to work for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10753521/7194773 I read it there, didn't ever test it. Maybe you have a different version of Windows. I saw your comment there, will have to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I used the winapi, but I looked up [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073(VS.85).aspx) and I was not able to find the CreateConsole API function. So my guess is that CreateConsole is legacy stuff and has been replaced by AttachConsole. So there is probably no difference, but CreateConsole has probably been deprecated.