# What is the difference between DETACH_PROCESS and CREATE_NO_WINDOW process creation flags for CreateProcess function?

Tags: windows, process, operating-system, system

I try to understand the difference between these two process creation flags. The [Process Creation Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags) documentation is not clear about the distinction.

- Does `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` cause the process to have a console (standard input/output streams initialized) without displaying a window while `DETACH_PROCESS` has no console at all?
- What are the implications for a child-of-a-child process?
- What would be the behavior matrix that describes what happens at each combination of (parent has console, parent doesn't have console) X (child executable requires console (`main`), child executable does not require console (`WinMain`))?

Comment: What do you mean by "each combination"? MSDN clearly states: "*This flag is ignored if the application is not a console application, or if it is used with either `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` or `DETACHED_PROCESS`.*" for `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`. So in a sense they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I meant combinations for child and parent being console or non-console executables. If the parent is a non-console application and I launch a console application from it with DETACH_PROCESS flag, would the child error out if it needs the console.

Comment: that depends entirely on the implementation of the C runtime. If I remember correctly, the MSVCRT would not cause problems in such a case. Other runtimes might.

Comment: I found that https://github.com/rprichard/win32-console-docs is a great resource for win console info.

Answer (score 23):

The difference is in what the started process can do.  In both cases it won't have a console.  But with the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` option it can call `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)` and get access to the parent's console window (if available).  That explicitly will not work when you specify `DETACH_PROCESS`.  The only option then is for the started process to use `AllocConsole()` to create its own console.

Or in other words, you can be sure that the started process will never be able to chatter into your own console by using `DETACH_PROCESS`.

Comment: Random note: powershell does *not* like DETACH_PROCESS.

Comment: To provide further info, `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` still inits a separate `conhost.exe` instance (just hidden) to parent the launched process and to marshall the process' input/output while `DETACHED_PROCESS` creates no 'conhost.exe' instance at all.

Comment: This answer seems to be incorrect. https://gist.github.com/josephcsible/f4dc0ca94adb41de1df358ed150d0c9b can write to its parent's console whether you start it with `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` or `DETACH_PROCESS`.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested what Hans Passant said about `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)`. However, I have found another difference based on testing.

Let's define a process tree to better explain what I mean:

```
A
|
+-- B
    |
    +-- C
```

With `DETACH_PROCESS`, only the started process (B) has no console — by default. If the started process starts console child processes (C), then each of those child process will be started in a new console. Furthermore, the started process B (or its children C) can still create a console by calling `AllocConsole`.

`CREATE_NO_WINDOW` is a "nuclear option" that's stronger than `DETACH_PROCESS`. Even the started process' children (C) don't get a console, not even if they call `AllocConsole`. Furthermore, Ctrl-C'ing the topmost process (A) won't terminate B and C, so it seems that `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` also includes an effect similar to starting a new process group.