# Win32 Execute a child process in the current console and exit without returning to parent

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, process

I'm currently working on a little win32 utility to read a configuration file/registry entry, and depending on the value, execute a child process with the current process command line arguments. It sounds simple enough, and has been done many times with many other programs. The only difference in this case is, I'm hoping to be able to do with without keeping the current process running in the background as it waits for the child process to end. Basically, I want to launch the child process, in the current console, passing along the stdin, etc, and then exit the current process, without the child process exiting, losing its console, or returning to the parent process of the current process.

Here's what I've written thus far to try and figure out a way to do this:

```c
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Macros for prettier code. */
#ifndef MAX_PATH
#   define MAX_PATH _MAX_PATH
#endif

#ifndef MAX_ENV
#   define MAX_ENV _MAX_ENV
#endif

/* Function Annotations/Declarations */
// Declare inline for MSVC's C compiler
#ifndef inline
#   define inline __inline
#endif

#ifndef bool
#   define bool BOOL
#   define true TRUE
#   define false FALSE
#endif

/* Utility macros */
#define log(x,...) _tprintf(TEXT("%s\n"), TEXT(x), __VA_ARGS__)
#define fatal(x,...) _tprintf(TEXT("ERROR: %s\n"), TEXT(x), __VA_ARGS__); ExitProcess(1)


// Search each process in the snapshot for id.
bool find_proc_id( HANDLE snap, DWORD id, LPPROCESSENTRY32 ppe )
{
    bool fOk;
    ppe->dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    for (fOk = Process32First( snap, ppe ); fOk; fOk = Process32Next( snap, ppe ))
        if (ppe->th32ProcessID == id)
            break;
    return fOk;
}

// Obtain the process and thread identifiers of the parent process.
bool parent_process(LPPROCESS_INFORMATION ppi)
{
    HANDLE hSnap;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
    THREADENTRY32   te;
    DWORD id = GetCurrentProcessId();
    bool fOk;

    hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS|TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, id );

    if (hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return FALSE;

    find_proc_id( hSnap, id, &pe );
    if (!find_proc_id( hSnap, pe.th32ParentProcessID, &pe ))
    {
        CloseHandle( hSnap );
        return FALSE;
    }

    te.dwSize = sizeof(te);
    for (fOk = Thread32First( hSnap, &te ); fOk; fOk = Thread32Next( hSnap, &te ))
        if (te.th32OwnerProcessID == pe.th32ProcessID)
            break;

    CloseHandle( hSnap );

    ppi->dwProcessId = pe.th32ProcessID;
    ppi->dwThreadId = te.th32ThreadID;

    return fOk;
}

void execute_child(TCHAR *AppName)
{
    BOOL result;
    HANDLE hStdInput, hStdOutput, hStdError, hParent;
    TCHAR tempCmdLine[MAX_PATH * 2];  //Needed since CreateProcessW may change the contents of CmdLine
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation, parentInformation;
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo;

    if (!parent_process( &parentInformation )) {
        fatal("Could not get parent process.");
    }

    if(!(hParent = OpenProcess(
        PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |   
        PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD     | 
        PROCESS_VM_OPERATION |
        PROCESS_VM_WRITE,  // For CreateRemoteThread/WriteVirtualMemory
        FALSE, parentInformation.dwProcessId
    ))) {
        fatal("Could not open a handle to the parent process.");
    }

    memset(&processInformation, 0, sizeof(processInformation));
    memset(&startupInfo, 0, sizeof(startupInfo));

    if((hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || !hStdInput) {
        CloseHandle(hParent);
        fatal("Failed to get stdin.");
    }

    if((hStdOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || !hStdOutput) {
        CloseHandle(hParent);
        CloseHandle(hStdInput);
        fatal("Failed to get stdout.");
    }

    if((hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || !hStdError) {
        CloseHandle(hParent);
        CloseHandle(hStdInput);
        CloseHandle(hStdOutput);
        fatal("Failed to get stderr.");
    }

    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
    startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    startupInfo.hStdInput = hStdInput;
    startupInfo.hStdOutput = hStdOutput;
    startupInfo.hStdError = hStdError;

    if (!CreateProcess(
            AppName,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            TRUE,
            CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE|NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS|CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP|CREATE_SUSPENDED,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &startupInfo,
            &processInformation
    )){
        CloseHandle(hParent);
        CloseHandle(hStdInput);
        CloseHandle(hStdOutput);
        CloseHandle(hStdError);
        fatal("CreateProcess failed!");
    }

    CloseHandle( hParent );
    CloseHandle( hStdInput );
    CloseHandle( hStdOutput );
    CloseHandle( hStdError );
    FreeConsole();
    ResumeThread(processInformation.hThread);
    CloseHandle( processInformation.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( processInformation.hThread );
    ExitProcess(0);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    execute_child(TEXT("python.exe"));

    return 0;
}
```

Now, when executed from outside a console, this does exactly what I want it to. A python shell is opened and the parent.exe compiled from the source above is not running. However, when run from an existing command prompt, the following occurs:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\ShellEnv\j-tree\sbin\python\2.7x86>parent.exe

C:\ShellEnv\j-tree\sbin\python\2.7x86>ActivePython 2.7.2.5 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 24 2011, 12:21:10) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 'hi'
Unable to initialize device PRN

C:\ShellEnv\j-tree\sbin\python\2.7x86>
```

The console ends up stuck in a strange situation where both Python and command prompt are executing in the current window, and any input gets handed off to one or the other, or split between the two.

I'm assuming that command prompt is using WaitForSingleObject on the process/main thread of parent.exe, and when that process exits, continuing on with its execution. I've come up with a couple of theories that I may try to work around this:

- Assuming the dwThreadId returned from parent_process is correct, I could attempt to suspend the thread responsible for the creation of the current process, then inject code into my child process so that on exit, it resumes the thread. The flaw in this idea is that it assumes that parent.exe is being run from command prompt or something similar that is waiting on the exit of parent.exe. In cases where parent.exe is run asynchronously (ShellExecute from explorer, for instance), it would deadlock that application.
- Again, assuming I have the correct information, I could attempt to rewrite the virtual memory containing the PROCESS_INFORMATION struct of parent.exe to that of the child process. This would require a portable way of locating that memory block, however, and would also require me to check the process architecture of the current process, and of the parent process, and account for any differences there might be in the size of data types, etc. I'm also not 100% on whether or not the write restrictions when it comes to processes would allow me to even do this from the child process. (Which means I might have to inject code into a remote thread in the parent process to achieve this, which is a whole new headache)

Anyways, I'm really hoping there's some built-in API to handle this that I just can't find. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between DETACH_PROCESS and CREATE_NO_WINDOW process creation flags for createProcess function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371149/what-is-the-difference-between-detach-process-and-create-no-window-process-creat)

Comment: Not quite. Were I to create the python.exe process with CREATE_NO_WINDOW and inject code into the the python process to call AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS), I'd still run into the issue of Command Prompt resuming execution as soon as parent.exe's process exited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a member of the `exec` [family of functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/431x4c1w%28v=vs.110%29)?

Calling one of these functions replaces the current process with a newly created process.

Comment: While that does indeed replace the calling process with a new process, it doesn't seem as those it inherits the current console from our process, or in the cases where it does, I end up back in that same predicament where command prompt and the child process. (python) are executing in the same console at the same time, making my input split randomly across the two.