# Starting [detached] external application from C#

Tags: c#

When start another process using `Process()` class, newly created process is still associated with the one invoked the start command, which is in turn causing issues with monitoring software or even within the stirted application itself.

So the question is if it is possible to start an external binary detachad from the caller, as a fully standalone instance? (Like started directly)

Update:

There are some processes expected to be a subprocesses of a specific process.

Like IE usually a subprocess of explorer.exe.

But started from C# app.exe with `Process().start(@"path/to/iexplere.exe")` it is a subprocess of app.exe

So is it possible to attach it to expected explorer.exe?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: A "directly started" process also has a "parent" (e.g. CMD.EXE). One way to do what you want would be to exit the process that you used to start the "external application", right after you started it. Depending on how your management software works that could be enough.

Comment: "newly created process is still associated with the one invoked the start command," how so? It seems pretty isolated and standalone to me. Maybe you should ask about your monitoring software?

Comment: @Christian.K check question update pls

Comment: `So is it possible to attach it to expected explorer.exe?` - No.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i detach an exe from Process.Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737777/how-do-i-detach-an-exe-from-process-start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common approach is to start an intermediate process (let's call it the *child*) that in turn starts the binary you want to detach (the *grandchild*).

The intermediate process is then terminated, leaving the *grandchild* without direct parents.

You are not showing any code, so we can't help you more than that. You can start from here.

Comment: that will newer work or add code to prove. check question update as well plz

Comment: What you're asking is not possible. To the best of my knowledge, only a process can create its children, i.e. only `explorer.exe` can start processes that are attached to `explorer.exe`.

Comment: that is very close to th answer I whanted. Tryed to run explorer.exe with the argument to start IE, but got the same result :( thanks anyway ;)

Comment: marking your answer as corrert as it did the trick. add sample code next time ;)

Comment: Excellent! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround for it.

It includes two applications. Lets call them handle.exe and detacher.exe

handle code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process.Start(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "detacher.exe");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

detacher code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "google.com");
        }
```

handle starts detacher and proceeds.
detacher starts IE and terminates.
IE drops to process root and proceeds.

[image: resulting process explorer]