# How to NOT inherit stdin, stdout and stderr in CreateProcess() on Windows

Tags: c, windows, winapi, process

[`CreateProcessW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw), accepts a flag `bInheritHandles`. If it is set to `FALSE`, only `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are inherited, the others are not.

This is sometimes annoying to inherit everything, so it is possible to explicitly configure the handles to inherit using [extended startup info](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873). In that case, `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are **not** inherited by default, but they can be inherited by including them in the inherited handles in `UpdateProcThreadAttribute()`.

That way, it is possible to inherit only `stderr` for example.

But as a specific case, how to disable them all (including `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`)? `UpdateProcThreadAttribute()` fails if we pass a `NULL`/empty list for attribute `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST`.

Note that I don't want to redirect `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` in that case (I don't want to write to/read from them), I just want to disable them.

As a workaround, it is possible to create a dummy `HANDLE` and inherit it, so that `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` could be disabled, but it's a bit hacky. `bInheritHandles` set to `FALSE` does not work because it enables `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. Passing `DETACHED_PROCESS` might have other side effects (?).

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: "*I don't want to redirect `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` in that case (I don't want to write to/read from them), I just want to disable them*" - This sounds like a possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. WHY do you want to disable them? What is the root issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: I develop a program which executes some commands. Sometimes, I want the output and/or of these commands in my program console, sometimes I want to capture them (so I use pipes), sometimes I just want to execute the command silently.

Comment: "*sometimes I just want to execute the command silently*" - have you tried using the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` or `DETACH_PROCESS` flag on `CreateProcess()`? See [What is the difference between DETACH_PROCESS and CREATE_NO_WINDOW process creation flags for createProcess function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371149/)

Comment: Yes, I tested `DETACH_PROCESS`, it seems to work, but as mentioned in the question, I fear possible unexpected side effects.

Comment: *If it is set to FALSE, only stdin, stdout and stderr are inherited, the others are not.* - no. nothing inherited at this case

Comment: This is not what I observe: the output of the command is printed in the console. I build from Linux with MinGW, I don't know if this can be related.

Comment: inheriting its parent's console (attached to same conhost.exe) not mean inherit any handles. what process you create ? the best really use `DETACHED_PROCESS`.

Comment: OK, I will use `DETACHED_PROCESS` when I don't want to inherit any handle, and the "extended startup info" when I want to inherit at least one handle.

Comment: For reference, with this code: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/228e2c15f44849032e9006dce1e0c47ae6e108ee/app/src/sys/win/process.c#L45 the child process outputs (stdout and stderr) to the parent console.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, if `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` is set, and if `bInheritHandles` set to `FALSE`, then no handles are inherited at all, which is exactly what I want:

```
STARTUPINFOW si;
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);

// This is important to disable stdin, stdout and stderr
si.StartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

// si.hStdInput, si.hStdOutput and si.hStdError must not be set
```

EDIT: Alternatively, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70041646/how-to-not-inherit-stdin-stdout-and-stderr-in-createprocess-on-windows/70041804#comment123815316_70041646) passing `DETACHED_PROCESS` in `dwCreationFlags` (a parameter of `CreateProcess()`) also works.